# Changing Axis/legend names in Plotly express on a bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

currently I am trying to create a simple bar graph using Plotly express. My x and y parameters are both python lists and I am trying to change the axis names as well as the names on the legend. I have been reading through the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be an example of doing this with express. Does anyone know how to do this? My code is below:

```
import plotly.express as px

disbyyear = px.bar(x= years, y=repdis, title="Total Disbursments by Party")
disbyyear.add_bar(x=years, y=demdis)
#disbyyear.update_yaxes(y = 'Dollars USD')
disbyyear.update_layout(barmode = 'group')
disbyyear.show()
```

a picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xat8c.png)

I want to for example change the 'y' on the left to say USD or something. Any help is appreciated thank you.

edit:
thank yall for the axis naming, for the legend I am still struggling to understand the 'labels' parameter. from the documentation, you only seem to be able to edit the legend if you use a data frame , but not with lists

Comment: If you use update_layout, you can also set the following. `fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Year', yaxis_title='Dollars USD')`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `labels` keyword argument.

```
disbyyear = px.bar(x= years, y=repdis, title="Total Disbursments by Party", labels={'x': 'Year', 'y':'Dollars USD'})
```

Comment: this does not seem to work in general for me (e.g. didn't work for px.line()), but @r-beginners comment works

Comment: This does not work for px.bar

Comment: `px.bar(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}), labels={'value': 'Year', 'index':'Dollars USD'})` worked fine. Plotly 5.19.0. The values in the labels dict have to match whatever is by default on the axes.